# Remote installation issue

Tags: powershell, installation, windows-installer

I am trying to remotely install software on multiple servers via PowerShell.
My script is working great but there is one problem.

I have 2 scripts so I don't have to re-configure security policies because of Kerberos double-hop.

1st script is copying installers any needed data to my local computer, copying data to destination server, then it is calling 2nd script

2nd script is performing uninstallation of old application, installation of new app and cleanup of temporary data on target device.

The problem is, that during execution of uninstall or install command installation always fails. Event log says that installation started but failed with error 1603. If I try it with `Enter-PSSession` it works.

This is not working:

```
foreach ($comp in $computers.split()) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {
        msiexec.exe /i "c:\temp\MYAPP.msi" /L*V "C:\temp\LOG.log" /passive
    }
}
```

This is working:(don't want to use it cause it is not safe)

```
Enter-PSSession serverX
msiexec.exe /i "c:\temp\MYAPP.msi" /L*V "C:\temp\LOG.log" /passive
exit
```

Do any of you have idea what can be cause of this problem or how to solve it?

Comment: You have a spurious trailing double quote after the parameter `/passive`. Also, why are you trying to install an executable via `msiexec.exe`? The program is for installing MSI packages. For further help show scriptblock output and relevant parts of the installer log.

Comment: Post corrected, scriptblock is without output and which part of installation log will be helpful?

Comment: Start with the differences between the logs from the manual and the scripted attempt.

Comment: I have answered question why is error 1603 occuring during installation. Something during remote session forced installer to install application to another disk, I did not realize that and tried another installations with same results : error 1603(I found that in install logs)... Now I have to solve how to force installer to install it on disk C.

Comment: Problem solved with msiexec parameter TARGETDIR="path"